# Making a chessboard with graphics

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a chessboard with graphics in Java (with the pixels themselves - not just pasting squares), and it doesn't work quite the way I want it to. Here's my code:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
for(int y = 30; y < getHeight() - 318; y++){
   for(int x = 30; x < getWidth() - 70; x++){
      if((b % 2 != 0)){
        x+=80;
        b++;     //if odd row, skip to next horizontal square to color black
      }
      if((x % 80 == 30) && (a % 2 == 0)){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 80, 80); //make squares of 80 x 80 pixels
      }     
      x+=79;
      a++;
  }
y+=79;
b++;
}
```

(Don't worry about the - 318 and - 70 and such - I'll fix them later, they're not of much consequence right now.) The first row of the chessboard is normal - but the rest of the rows are offset because the rest of the first column is white, and not alternating with black. There's something wrong with b, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try modifying the program to print x, y, a and b each time through the loop. Are they changing the way you expect them to? If not, when does the first error occur, and can you explain why?

(Or fire it up in a debugger and step through it, watching the variables change. Which is a more elegant way of doing the same thing.)

I'll bet that once you see it happening, you'll figure out the problem and solution yourself.

Comment: so you are drawing black squares on a white background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be a little confused about which variables to use when you loop through the board. In some places you use a and b, which go up by 1 (it a = 1 and b = 2, they would seem to be referring to the square 1 step right from the top and two steps down), in other places you loop with x and y which are referring to screen pixels

I changed it a little to only use a and b, and we determine x and y only when we draw the squares. I also changed the logic to determine when a square is black or white - this might be wrong but there are only two ways to draw the chess board as either beginning black or beginning white.

```
//int a = 0, b = 0; // we will loop thorugh a,b instead
for(int a = 0; a < 8; a++){
   for(int b = 0; x < 8; x++){
      //b is for the horizontal axis and a for vertical
      if((a + b) % 2 == 0){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(30 + b * 80, 30 + a * 80, 80, 80); //make squares of 80 x 80 pixels
      }     
   }
}
```

Comment: I know it says to avoid saying thanks in comments, but... Wow! I would never have thought of that... A much more elegant solution, thank you!

Comment: Please remember to leave comments when you downvote. Otherwise they are relatively useless and annoying. Thanks

Comment: @user3125280 is it possible that in the second for loop you need to replace x++ with b++?